# Symfony2 + FOSUserBundle - CRUD Generation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I have a pretty STD Symfony2 project with FOSUserBundle installed. 
Currently there is only basic user class took from FOS documentation:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/AppBundle/Entity/User.php


namespace Acme\AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setting = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        // your own logic
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

There is already a database and table based on this entity. What I am trying to do now is generate CRUD using command-line generator. But when I am generating CRUD with command:

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud
```

I am getting files with only ID field, it looks like that CRUD generator is not paying attention to parent class and its fields.

I guess it is not normal behavior, but I cannot find - why, what is happening ?

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php shows that the base User does not contain any Doctrine annotations for creating columns. Where are the infos about the other properties?

Comment: Hmmm I am not sure but - here ?
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/doctrine/model/User.orm.xml

Comment: possible dup/related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058785/doctrine-doesnt-map-fields-from-fosuserbundle-user-class